# Does Ubuntu recognize and use my AMD dedicated GPU?

Tags: 16.04, hybrid-graphics, amd-graphics, gpu-driver

I have an Asus notebook with a AMD APU (A6-7310) and a dGPU (R5 M320). I know that 16.04 doesn't support the proprietary AMD drivers but I'm getting super lackluster performance in games (always under 25fps at 720p in Torchlight II) and am wondering if this is because the OS fails to activate my dGPU.

```
xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 1
Provider 0: id: 0x53 cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 2 outputs: 2 associated providers: 0 name:MULLINS @ pci:0000:00:01.0
```

Does this mean that only the iGPU is working? If so, is it possible to make only the dGPU available (if you have to choose)? I haven't found any such option or any option pertaining to graphics at all for that matter in the UEFI.

The graphics line in system information reads

> Gallium 0.4 on AMD MULLINS (DRM 2.43.0, LLVM 3.8.0)

There's no mention of my dGPU.

Output of

> lspci | grep VGA

```
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mullins [Radeon R4/R5 Graphics] (rev 40)
```

Output of [glxinfo](http://pastebin.com/YFiSFcKy)

Comment: Okay, given there is no mention at all of your dGPU, it's not using it.  That said, the output may be either one.  After all the dGPU is an R5, and the integrated one is an R4.  The output says R4/R5.

The output of the system information indicates it is using the 3D accelerated open source drivers.  That is ok.  JUst like Intel, AMD has contributed heavily to support the open source drivers.

I understand this is no help to you, I just wanted to clarify.

Comment: Added output of "glxinfo". I really don't know which GPU is being used but judging from the abysmal 3D performance I'm guessing it's the iGPU.

Comment: Most likely.  I can't help you further as I just hoped the glxinfo would give us information that we didn't know yet.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a reply, and shouldn't be upvoted.  I see two things here. You have an APU and a dGPU (Discrete GPU).  That's rather important, because it means you have two graphics "cards", of which one is on-chip.

According to the [product page at AMD](http://products.amd.com/en-us/search/APU/AMD-A-Series-Processors/AMD-A6-Series-APU-for-AIOs/A6-7310-with-Radeon%E2%84%A2-R4-Graphics/150), the A6-7310, features a R4 series Radeon (unspecified).  I have the impression that this is supposed to be equivalent of the NVidia Optimus technology, which gives you a discrete NVida card for high-performance use, and the Integrated Intel for normal desktop use.  The idea is to save battery by turning off/not using the discrete card, when it's not in use.  The NVidia technology is supported lacklusterly, but it does work (I happen to have a Dell XPS L502x which has this feature.  Since 14.04 it's become usable)

I have no experience with this on AMD, but it might help you finding further information.  What I'd do for starters, is see whether both cards are detected: `lspci | grep VGA`.  This should show you two entries.

Also, try checking what "System Settings" -> "Details" tells you about your systems graphics.  Normally it should show you the one it's currently using.

You might also want to install "mesa-utils" and launch "glxinfo" to get more information about what is actually being used.